# How do I pass param for number search to API?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is how the API expects the number search
https:{{url}}/search?numberFilters=cost=43
Note that cost can create various forms of searches
e.g.

```js
numberFilters=cost<394  
numberFilters=cost>=2  
numberFilters=cost>=100,cost<500
```

This is my code which has bugs. I can't dynamically pass in cost or cost range result. It also doesn't return result for numbers like 200. The problem I'm facing is that I can't correctly pass the number or numbers in the structure expected by the API.

This is what I tried

```
import axios, { AxiosError } from "axios";

export default async function SearchByFilter(
  boolResult?: boolean,
  sellerResult?: string,
  numberSearch?: number | null
): Promise<AllData[]> {
  const url = "https://search-practice-backend.vercel.app/api/v1/search";
  const params: { [key: string]: string | boolean } = {
    promote: boolResult || false,
    seller: sellerResult || "",
  };

  if (numberSearch !== null && numberSearch !== undefined) {
    params.numberFilters = `cost${<|>|<=|>=|=}${numberSearch}`;
  }

  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(url, { params });
    return data.final as AllData[];
  } catch (error: unknown) {
    if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
      console.log(error.response);
    }
    throw error;
  }
}
```

```
interface NumberSearchProps {
  numberSearch: number | null;
  setNumberSearch: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number | null>>;
  dataResults: AllData[] | null;
}

export const NumberSearch = ({
  numberSearch,
  setNumberSearch,
}: NumberSearchProps) => {
  function handleChange(value: number) {
    setNumberSearch(value);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Search cost</p>
      <input
        type="number"
        name="numberSearch"
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(Number(e.target.value))}
        value={numberSearch !== null ? numberSearch : ""}
      />
      <p>or enter min and max numbers</p>
      <input
        type="number"
        name="numberSearch"
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(Number(e.target.value))}
        value={numberSearch !== null ? numberSearch : ""}
        placeholder="min"
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        name="numberSearch"
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(Number(e.target.value))}
        value={numberSearch !== null ? numberSearch : ""}
        placeholder="max"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
import SearchByFilter from "@/lib/SearchByFilter";
import { useState } from "react";
import { BooleanSearch } from "./BooleanSearch";
import { SellerSearch } from "./SellerSearch";
import { NumberSearch } from "./NumberSearch";

export const FilterSearch: React.FC = () => {
  const [boolResult, setBoolResult] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [sellerResult, setSellerResult] = useState<string>("");
  const [numberSearch, setNumberSearch] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const [dataResults, setDataResults] = useState<AllData[] | null>(null);

  async function handleSubmit() {
    try {
      const results = await SearchByFilter(
        boolResult === null ? undefined : boolResult,
        sellerResult === "" ? "" : sellerResult,
        numberSearch ?? undefined
      );
      setDataResults(results);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <BooleanSearch
        boolResult={boolResult === null ? false : (boolResult as boolean)}
        setBoolResult={setBoolResult}
        dataResults={dataResults}
      />
      <hr />
      <SellerSearch
        sellerResult={sellerResult}
        setSellerResult={setSellerResult}
        dataResults={dataResults}
      />
      <hr />
      <NumberSearch
        numberSearch={numberSearch}
        setNumberSearch={setNumberSearch}
        dataResults={dataResults}
      />
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Filter</button>
      {dataResults && (
        <ul>
          {dataResults.map((data) => (
            <div key={data._id}>
              <h3>{data.title}</h3>
              <li>{data.seller}</li>
              <li>{data.cost}</li>
            </div>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
interface AllData {
  _id: string;
  title: string;
  cost: number;
  seller: string;
}
```

This is what I expected. Typing a number in the input with name numberSearch will return results that match that exact number. Typing numbers in the numberSearchMin or numberSearchMax will return results of numbers between the range

Comment: I'm unable to implement search via numberFilter, cost.

Comment: Ok, but what bug are you facing? What obstacle are you encountering? Having more context about your actual problem helps to understand how to help you fixing it

Comment: I can't dynamically pass a number or numbers in terms of range to numberFilter so that it can be correctly queried.